# Ref forwarding. Performing actions on a ref before passing it through

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to make a HOC that would make use of the underlying dom element. I was looking into the [ref-forwarding API](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) in order to do this.

Effectively, I am using a context component to locate the position of DOM nodes and register their positions. I was trying something like this:

```
export default function createIntersectable<TProps = {}>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<TProps & { ref: React.RefObject<HTMLElement> }>,
) {
  class Intersectable extends React.PureComponent<ComponentProps<TProps>> {
    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.register(this.props.forwardedRef.current);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.props.unregister(this.props.forwardedRef.current);
    }

    render() {
      const { forwardedRef, ...rest } = this.props;
      return <Component ref={forwardedRef} {...rest} />;
    }
  }

  return React.forwardRef((props: TProps, ref: React.RefObject<any>) => {
    return (
      <IntersectionContext.Consumer>
        {({ register, unregister }) => (
          <Intersectable
            {...props}
            forwardedRef={ref}
            register={register}
            unregister={unregister}
          />
        )}
      </IntersectionContext.Consumer>
    );
  });
}
```

I am then consuming it like this:

```
renderNodes() {
  return this.props.nodes.map((node) => {
    const ref = React.createRef();
    <Node {...node} ref={ref} key={node.id} />
  });
}
```

Where `Node` is a component wrapped by `createIntersectable`.

However, I get `null` for my `ref` at all times. I'm not sure of the appropriate way to do this.

What's the correct way to forward a ref with react 16.3 in a HOC?